# Laravel custom helper class - undefined function

Tags: laravel

I made a custom helper class (`helpers.php`) in `app/MyHelpers`.

For testing purposes I made in function in that file:

```
<?php

function MyTestHelper(){

    return 'title';
}

?>
```

I registered the helper class in **composer.json**:

```
"autoload": {
        
        "psr-4": {
            "Illuminate\\": "src/Illuminate/",
            "Illuminate\\Support\\": ["src/Illuminate/Macroable/", "src/Illuminate/Collections/"]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/MyHelpers/helpers.php",
            "src/Illuminate/Collections/helpers.php",
            "src/Illuminate/Events/functions.php",
            "src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php",
            "src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php"
       ]
    },
```

I ran `composer dump-autoload`. Trying to call the function in a blade template results in an error:

```
Call to undefined function MyTestHelper()
```

I have no idea what I did wrong. I created a new Laravel project and did the exact same steps and the helper function does work in that project.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you registered it in the correct `composer.json` the one in the root of your project ? That one looks like the composer.json which is under `vendor` in the illuminate folder (which you should not be touching)

Comment: I owe you one, apokryfos! I was indeed working in the wrong composer file. 

Answer (score 1):

You may have to run the following composer command because you have changed the autoload in `composer.json`

```
composer dump-autoload
```